# Forcing a webserver that only works on localhost:8080 to work outside as well

Tags: web-server, http

(pardon my ignorance, I am not familiar enough with http to understand the background of this. I'd be grateful if you could enlighten me).

I have a webserver that runs on http://localhost:8080. However, it doesn't work when I type my machine name (I am on a machine with a DNS name behind a firewall). Even on my own machine, if i write "machinename:8080" it fails, but going to "localhost:8080" works.

Why is this? Is there a way to force my way into enabling "machinename:some_other_port" to just serve whatever localhost:8080 serves?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what webserver?

Comment: If you type the IP address of your localhost, what does it do? ie, http:\\YourIPAddress:8080

Comment: If you could provide the application/server/host machine information we would probably be able to help you better. :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what exactly webserver you use.  It looks like it listens for incoming connections on interface 127.0.0.1 (localhost).  You need to configure it to listen on interface 0.0.0.0 (which means all interfaces - all IP numbers assigned to this computer).  How to configure it depends on the webserver.

Comment: It could also be a hostname based virtualhost, meaning that it is only listening specifically for 'localhost', even on all bindings

Comment: Or it could be just a DNS issue...

Comment: Or a firewalling problem...